# Queries on unbounded knapsack

Tags: graphs, optimization, shortest-path

Given $n$ types of items with integer cost $c_{i}$ (*there is an unlimited number of items of each type*), such that $c_{i} \leq c$ for all $i = 1, 2, \dots, n$, answer (a lot of) queries of form "is there some set of items of total weight $w$?" in time $O(1)$ with some kind of precalculation in time $O(n c \log c)$.

I've got a hint - for every $i = 0, 1, 2, \dots, c - 1$ find minimal $x$ such that there is a set of items with total weight $x$ and $x \equiv i \quad (\bmod c)$. How to calculate all $x$'s and how to use them to answer the queries?

This problem is somehow related to graphs and shortest paths, but I don't understand the connection between actual knapsack-like thing and graphs (maybe there is some graph with paths of desired weight?).

Source: problem 76 on [neerc.ifmo.ru wiki](http://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%90%D0%B8%D0%A1%D0%94-year2015-%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC2).

Comment: Try the techniques shown here: https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/dynamic-programming/info.  That said, I don't understand the hint; I wonder if it's not quite right.  For instance, if $c_1=17$, $c_2=19$, $c=20$, I don't see how the hint helps.  Can you [edit] your question to credit the original source of this exercise, please?

Comment: @D.W. I've added the source (by the way, the original statement is in Russian).

Comment: Thanks!  I have some suggestions. Can you solve it first with $n=2$?  If so, show your solution.  Can you solve it with $n=3$?  Show your solution. I am not sure whether the hint is 100% right.  Maybe consider the following variant of the hint as well: replace the $c$ in the hint with a different variable $d$; figure out how to solve the hint for arbitrary $d$; and then pick how to set $d$.  I don't know how to solve it for arbitrary $n$, so I am not sure whether these will lead to a solution, but they "smell" promising to me.